# Activeperl to Strawberry perl

Tags: excel, windows, strawberry-perl, activeperl

We have some trouble installing strawberry in a server that have an existing version of activeperl.

This is a server that use perl to create an excel file, using modules like :

`use XML::Twig use File::Basename use Excel::Writer::XLSX`

We have tried to uninstall activeperl to install strawberry, we have modified windows path, and then runned the script.

No error following this run, but the excel out file is corrupted.

We have uninstalled strawberry to install again activeperl and, following new script run, the excel out file is fine again.

I don't really know how perl works, but it there a trouble with the used modules ?

is strawberry running with activeperl modules so it don't like it ?
the modules may be missing in strawberry, but the script don't crash ?

thank you guys :)